# How to deal with requests authorization header that seems to expire

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am utilizing requests to download a document from a website. To do this I am using a collection of r.get and r.post to navigate the website. The issue that I am having is that one of the headers, "authorization", changes with each request. Since the tool scrapes the website every few seconds, this is not working. My method for getting the necessary cookies, parameters and headers is via the cURL data of the relevant GET or POST. Below is the relevant piece of code. The request causing my issues is the final r.get request that is passed cookies2, params2, headers2.

```
        self.cookies2 = {
            '_ga_CD30TTEK1F': 'GS1.1.1615956693.4.1.1615957453.0',
            '_ga': 'GA1.1.290601150.1614925497',
            '_4c_': 'bVHBrpswEPyVyuc4scEYwy1VqypSVUV6ba%2FI2CZY4RlkHGgS5d%2B7Vgnta8uF3ZnZ2V3vHc2tcaiknGZFlrMsEQXfoLO5jqi8I291%2FE2oREyQXBhNMdFSYdbUFAuWcMxr0qQ5K%2FI6r9EG%2FYheSZITClCasccGaff00KaRly6ssjSjGRVccAIyO4RFF4fJ04KKPKHkrTYiUft0lOi%2FvJ9Xq4UQRUHfSiMC0mn1okJKzeoUM8YZht0krhPYsK4bmdI6yTQpnu3ia4mM5hkvNiiEDjBB4geOalgc70j12kTnYkvplkJxuEGKE0YgNi52HcMJ4k%2F76tvhA6RJQTihNCNbaMKKJINnBP7ioQVqQxjGcreb53l7GYfQb0%2F9tOuM9M66E5ZOY2%2FG%2FuKVGXd901hlZYdP8mZCMP8AeJDBuDCC%2FeB7fVGhCtchzjub%2Bt2oz0BoM1llqtnq0MZFEkF%2Bo62xpxaOhmD1iA4%2BLgDRbJ3u57%2BrFnSt4ixqj8sQJfoC2VcvtXmV%2FvwEDsfqs5yrY99Zda0OrukX4rsBN%2F8nsp%2Bk7aqPnVHB986q6r29VS%2FX1cmFrtqrYCcbrFkbmjHY195dq5fBGNUuxON5Z05YSuHOgix3Fpz9OvTj8RM%3D',
            'ADRUM': 's=1616013800421&r=https%3A%2F%2Fptab.uspto.gov%2F%3F-1483723136',
            '_gid': 'GA1.3.1332106114.1615871533',
            '_gat': '1',
        }

        self.headers2 = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhcHBsaWNhdGlvblVzZXJJZCI6MTUwMzc1LCJlbXBsb3llZUlkIjpudWxsLCJ1c2VySWQiOm51bGwsInVzZXJOYW1lIjoiYXJob2RlczNAdmlsbGFub3ZhLmVkdSIsImZpcnN0TmFtZSI6IkFuZHJldyIsIm1pZGRsZU5hbWUiOm51bGwsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiUmhvZGVzIiwiZW1haWxJZCI6ImFyaG9kZXMzQHZpbGxhbm92YS5lZHUiLCJwaG9uZSI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNjE2MDI3NTUzMTg5LCJleHAiOjE2MTYwMjkzNjU4MzMsImlzcyI6IlBUQUJFMkUiLCJlbmRFZmZlY3RpdmVEYXRlIjpudWxsLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJQVEFCRTJFX0V4dGVybmFsX1VzZXIiXX0.CeE0HM_W2bef2Sc7PfvLJJTcDDYKW6CEgzqpDhyBgMU',
            'ADRUM': 'isAjax:true',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Referer': 'https://ptab.uspto.gov/',
        }

        self.params2 = (
            ('cacheFix', '1616027845608'),
            ('extUserSearchView', 'Y'),
        )
...
    def main(self):
        with requests.Session() as r:
            # Get initial document count
            r.post ( self.url_origin, headers=self.headers, params=self.params, cookies=self.cookies, data=self.data )
            r.get ( self.url_search )
            r.post ( self.url_enter, headers=self.headers1, params=self.params1,
                     cookies=self.cookies1, data=self.data1 )
# Below request is the one giving me issues
            response = r.get (self.url_doc_view,
                               headers=self.headers2,
                               params=self.params2, cookies=self.cookies2)
```

The code works as it should for about 30 minutes after copying the headers data into the script but then gives me the below error after about 30 minutes when I print request.json():

```
b'[{"code":"0","message":"There was a problem with your request.","type":null}]'
```

It is as if the headers data expires after a period of time. Once the error comes up, I have to go back to the website and copy the cURL data into the self.headers2 variable.

What am I doing wrong here or how can I code it so I do not need to keep updating the headers values every 30 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the header "Authorization" will be expired after 30 minutes; you need to find out how to generate a new one.

Usually, it returns from the server or is generated by Javascript.
For the first case, you can search the "Authorization" value from the devtool network panel.
For the second case, you need to debug JavaScript:

1. Make a breakpoint before the request with an Authorization header.
2. Check the call stack to find a variable with the value.
3. Find out how to generate the variable before it. Usually, it will be a function; then you can call it on the console to see whether it can generate a new one.
4. Then, try to make the function work by extracting the code to a JavaScript file. After that, you can call it by nodejs or excjs.